# Reading and expanding a Racket source file

Tags: racket

I need to read a Racket source file and run it through macro expansion. I have a simple test file that Racket itself happily accepts:

```
C:\ayane>type factorial.rkt
#lang racket
(provide factorial)

(define (factorial n)
 (if (<= n 1)
  1
  (* n (factorial (sub1 n)))))
```

Now I try from the REPL:

```
C:\ayane>racket
Welcome to Racket v6.5.
> (read-accept-reader #t)
> (expand (with-input-from-file "factorial.rkt" (lambda () (read-syntax "factorial.rkt"))))
#<syntax::1 (module factorial racket (#%m...>
```

So far so good. Now the same thing from a test program:

```
C:\ayane>type test.rkt
#lang racket
(read-accept-reader #t)
(expand (with-input-from-file "factorial.rkt"
                              (lambda ()
                               (read-syntax "factorial.rkt"))))

C:\ayane>racket test.rkt
factorial.rkt::1: module: unbound identifier;
 also, no #%app syntax transformer is bound
  at: module
  in: (module factorial racket (#%module-begin (provide factorial) (define (factorial n) (if (<= n 1) 1 (* n (factorial (sub1 n)))))))
  context...:
   C:\ayane\test.rkt: [running body]
```

So it looks like the same code works interactively but not in a program. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify which namespace `expand` should use to lookup top-level variables (i.e. variables not bound in the program).

For example:

```
 (parameterize ([current-namespace (make-base-namespace)])
     (expand ...))
```

For more information see the comments in the file below in which I attempt to explain the relationship between namespaces and expand:

https://github.com/soegaard/meta/blob/master/runtime/racket-eval.rkt#L122

Answer (score 5):

The answer from @soegaard addresses the immediate issue, but if you want a comprehensive program that reimplements expansion from primitives, you can look at

https://github.com/samth/pycket/blob/master/pycket/pycket-lang/expand.rkt